# Lightning Components version strategy

Tags: lightning-aura-components, versioning

I want to implement a component versioning in lightning. The versioning would help me when I want to deprecate a component and start to use a new componet without having any impact for the users.

I implemented visualforce page versioning using redirect pages yet, but a similar approach is not applicable to lightning components.

What is the best way to realize component versioning in lightning?

Comment: You might be interested in the indirection discussed in this [Managing Dependency Injection within Salesforce](https://andyinthecloud.com/2018/07/15/managing-dependency-injection-within-salesforce/) post. Though I suggest you need to be clear about the benefit you will get before you introduce the complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually, since you can nest components, you could just place one in the other:

```
<aura:component>
   <!-- attributes go here -->
   <!-- optional: include a deprecated notice, perhaps to admins only? -->
   <c:componentDeprecated />
   <!-- give new component values -->
   <c:componentV2 attr1="{!v.attr1}" attr2="{!v.attr2}" ... />
</aura:component>
```

If you do that, make sure that you're eventually cleaning up the old deprecated versions to avoid excessive nesting, which would have a performance penalty, but I think this approach makes it simple enough to switch versions, since they only have to change a single line of code (assuming full compatibility).

I don't think that this was something really well thought out, much like how they didn't really allow this in Visualforce (we work around it instead of using some special system-platform-specific versioning feature).

Comment: If only we could version each of our own components, and then declaratively specify the versions of our dependencies! Just like a whole managed package has a version...

Comment: @RohitKunal Yes, that'd be nice, or even something like how components have API version dependencies. But unfortunately, whatever solution you would design would require an interstitial component to implement dependency injection, at minimum.

Answer (score 1):

One can insert versioning logic into the markup like so:

```
<aura:component>
 ...
 <aura:if isTrue="{!Version > 1.0}"> 
  <c:newVersionFunctionality/> 
 </aura:if> 
 <c:oldVersionFunctionality/> 
 ...
</aura:component>
```

- In Apex, use `System.requestVersion()`
- In ControllerJS/HelperJS use
  `component.getVersion()`
- In component markup use `{!Version}`